# How to read bundled react native code (index.android.bundle)

Tags: react-native, reverse-engineering

I've got a decompiled android app which is based on react native. Does anyone know how i can find out where in the code these labels are used or who is referencing e.default?

```
__d(function(g, r, i, a, m, e, d) {
  var t = r(d[0]);
  Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
    value: !0
  }), e.default = void 0;
  var l = r(d[1]),
    u = t(r(d[2])),
    n = [{
        id: l.Sal.SIX,
        label: u.default.t('test.broke')
    }, {
        id: l.Sal.SEVEN,
        label: u.default.t('test.even')
    }];
  e.default = n
}
```

All of these "modules" (or components, i actually really dont know what those are since i've never worked with react native) starts with "__d".

Answer (score 0):

Same here. I know that __d injects dependencies for the function (How f...ing elegant). variable t, is some sort of interface that let's the js code interact with the native platform. d is like a key list and r is a function that retrieves the actual variables and such using the keys stored in d. Making sense of pure dalvik (or Java heck even ELF) binary is easier than obfuscated js